# Variable typeof object in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, typeof, strict, use-strict

This piece of JavaScript ran fine without `"use strict";`. But how can I check if a global variable exists with strict mode and what type it has without running into a `undeclared variable` error?

```
if (!(typeof a === 'object')) {
    a = ... /* complex operation */
}
```

Comment: You have to define `a` somewhere before hand.  Perhaps in the most outer scope if you want it to behave like a global.

Comment: @Jamen I found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32247052/22470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a valid way to check if a global variable `a` exists without triggering a warning in JavaScript.

> The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property.

[`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) does not trigger a warning when the requested variable name does not exist in the global space!

```
'use strict';
if (!window.hasOwnProperty('a')) {
    window.a = ... 
    // Or
    a = ...
}
```

To make sure `a` is an object use

```
'use strict';
if (!(window.hasOwnProperty('a') && typeof a === 'object')) {
    window.a = ... 
    // Or
    a = ...
}
```

Comment: This is a very convoluted alternative to `if(typeof(a) !== 'undefined') ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating implicit globals is an error in strict mode. You have to create the global explicitly:

```
window.a = ... /* complex operation */
```

`typeof a` should still work as before.

Comment: In other words: there is no way to check if a variable is already declared in strict mode?

Comment: What makes you think that? I said *"`typeof a` should still work as before"*, with which I meant "non-strict" mode. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have a non declared variable... you must put this first: `var a = {};`. But, here is how I check those kind of things.

```
var utils = {
  //Check types
  isArray: function(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == "[object Array]";
  },
  isObject: function(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == "[object Object]";
  },
  isString: function(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == "[object String]";
  },
  isNumber: function(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == "[object Number]";
  },
  isFunction: function(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == "[object Function]";
  }
}

var a = ""; // Define first, this is your real problem.
if(!utils.isObject(a)) {
  // something here.
}
```

Comment: You don't even really have to explicitly give it a value either.  You can simply do `var a;`

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. I put some value because if he is checking what kind of variable he has is because he already has a value... if not this make non sense. But, it is true, the problem is he never declare the variable.

Comment: I want to check if the variable IS ALREADY declared and if it is an object.

Comment: "use strict", demands all variables has to be declared, its because the scope, so, if you have to check that don't use strict mode. If you are strict enough you will never has the need to check if a variable is declared.
You have to choose, is simple as that. Strict mode or undeclared variables.

In order to check, you can do 'a != undefined' and then check what kind of Object is (because in Javascript all is an Object, check my utils variable of you have a doubt).

Comment: *"because in Javascript all is an Object"* Primitive values are not objects.

Comment: Except for null and undefined, all primitive values have object equivalents that wrap around the primitive values. Lets be a bit more pragmatic, that sentence have a context...